# Prove that every nonempty set of real numbers that is bounded from below has an inﬁmum

Tags: real-analysis

Every non-empty subset of $R$ having a lower bound has an inﬁmum.

Since $S$ has a lower bound, then the set $S' = \{−x \mid x ∈ S\}$ has an upper bound and hence by completeness property has a supremum. Now show that if $M = \sup(S)$ then $−M = \inf(S)$.

Is there other way to prove it??

Comment: My guess is that, since M has a supremum and -M is it's opposite then the supremum of M becomes an infinum for -M.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be assuming every set that is non-empty and bounded above has a supremum.  If we assume that, then there is another way: Let $T$ be the set of all lower bounds of $-S$.  Then $T$ has a supremum (since every member of $-S$ is an upper bound of $T$).  Try to show that that is the infimum of $-S$ and that it is equal to $-\sup S$.

Comment: I would say there's nothing to choose between these two approaches.